# SOIL runtime error in Release Mode - Unhandled exception (ntdll.dll)

Tags: c++, opengl, release, soil

I am trying to load texture into GLuint (unsigned int). I did the following:

```
material[materialNum].texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture((fileLocation + "/" + mtlBufferStr).c_str(), SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT);
```

This code works on debug mode. But on release mode I got run time error on "_file.c" (I did not create it) and the run time error is:

> Unhandled exception at 0x771A8E19 (ntdll.dll) in Win32.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014

Why this run time error appears only on release mode and how do I solve it?

Edit: I add the full code of the program with the path of the file and without the GLuint. Stiil the same problem:

```
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow )
{

AllocConsole();
HANDLE handle_out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
int hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long) handle_out, _O_TEXT);
FILE* hf_out = _fdopen(hCrt, "w");
setvbuf(hf_out, NULL, _IONBF, 1);
*stdout = *hf_out;

SOIL_load_OGL_texture("models/havoc/tex_0007_1.dds", SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT);                         
}
```

Comment: This should not work in debug mode either, you have no OpenGL context when you make this call and you are telling SOIL to load the texture into the current GL context.

Comment: I have deleted some code to make this code more comfortable to you. But in the real code there is OpenGL context.